# "Require not allowed here" after drupal update

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal-7

Just upgraded Drupal to 7.55 and got a 500 error.
Opened up `logs/error.log` and saw this appearing since the upgrade:

```
<site-root>/.htaccess: Require not allowed here
```

I see that the update has replaced this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|^(\.(?!well-known).*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|composer\.(json|lock))$|^#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig\.save)$">
        Order allow,deny
    </FilesMatch>
```

With this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|^(\.(?!well-known).*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|composer\.(json|lock))$|^#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig\.save)$">
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order allow,deny
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

I've changed it back and now it seems OK, but what is the problem here?

Comment: Your server configuration must allow that you use that directive in .htaccess. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#require says, “Override: AuthConfig”, and that means [`AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) needs to include `AuthConfig` or be set to `All`

Comment: Thanks! I added AuthConfig to the AllowOverride list in /sites-enabled/foo.conf and now it works. Please can you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> .htaccess: Require not allowed here

Your server configuration must allow that you use that directive in .htaccess

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#require says,

> Override: AuthConfig

and that means `AllowOverride` needs to include `AuthConfig` or be set to `All`, for you to be able to use the `Require` directive in .htaccess context.

Answer (score 1):

"Require" is a type of AuthConfig directives. You need to specify, in  httpd.conf, that type of directives is allowed in .htaccess.

```
<Directory DIRECTORY>
    ...
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>
```

Here DIRECTORY is the directory where .htaccess is located.

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride